# How can I make Ubuntu seem more friendly to someone used to Windows 10?

Tags: 18.04, windows-10, ux

Which configuration steps I should follow in order to make Ubuntu 18.04 seem more friendly to someone used to Windows 10?

For example: the extension "dash to panel", when the panel is at the bottom, provides a closer windows-like experience.

I'm not asking for icon themes in particular, nor templates, but functional configuration tips and ideas.

Comment: If they're used to Word and Google Chrome, just use Chrome and WPS office. Beyond that, it's the same as going from Windows to Mac. You'll have to learn a bit about UI elements, like what's a dock and what's an indicator, but beyond that mondern apps are same on any platform.  It's like driving Ford after Toyota. Same principle different dashboard

Comment: It's a shame this question is put on hold. I think is a pretty good question, one that can draw many ideas on how to help people feel more comfortable using Ubuntu after many years on Windows. There is nothing wrong with it being too broad in this case.

Comment: [Check out Kubuntu 18.04](https://kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-18-04-has-been-released/). By default, it has the taskbar at the bottom, the start menu in the lower left, and the clock and system tray in the lower right. On application windows, the minimize, maximize, and close buttons are on the upper-right corner. Plus, like the [Super User](https://superuser.com) site for Windows help, they can get help for free here. If you have an older system, Xubuntu 18.04 is pretty lightweight and can have its taskbar moved to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @estebanknobl: "can draw many ideas", i. e. open-endedness, is the precise reason why it's a bad question for Stack Exchange's Q&A model. The question itself has merit but it doesn't fit here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think it does fit here. "Which configuration steps I should follow in order to make Ubuntu 18.04 seem more friendly to someone used to Windows 10" it's a somewhat broad question that can, nevertheless, draw many specific and relevant answers, useful to me and many other users.

Answer (score 4):

The absolutely best way is to **stop using Windows** as a crutch and **dive into Ubuntu**.  The longer a person uses the crutch and keep trying to make Ubuntu windows would be the longer it'll take them to recognize the ease and facility of Ubuntu.

Ubuntu is friendly.  It's substantially less of a curb of going from Windows XP or Windows 7 to Windows 10.  When Microsoft made a radical change, moving to Windows 10, people kicked and screamed a little, but they moved on and adjusted.

The same would happen if when a user thanks of his goal, and just go for it in the environment the way it is.

Click on the applications menu and click on what you want to run, or type letters to bring up the app you want to use, and just use it.

Having used a computer can be springboard to the new environment... how to move the mouse, other elements of navigating.  Other than that, look toward the task/object... don't look for Windows.

**That is how to make Ubuntu seem more friendly to someone used to Windows 10.**

You could add a secondary dock (Cairo-dock) from the repository.  It makes Ubuntu resemble the Mac.

**The Cairo-dock is a way to have a panel at the bottom** as per the reference in your question.

It can be installed with this command:

```
$ sudo apt install cairo-dock
```

There are a number of other docks and tools you can install from the repository.  If you install one you don't like, you can just as easily remove it with:

```
$ sudo apt remove cairo-dock.
```

To run a new installed application, such as Cairo-dock, search the applications menu.

Comment: Maybe some words have a different connotation from my generation.  Learning curb brings to mind (as what I intended) using current experiences to be ahead of the game when something new comes along.  Sort of another way of expressing what I get from Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy's reference to same for Windows and Mac when he described some of the applications.  It was intended to be the opposite of what you are imaging.  Take from your experience and expand upon it in the new environment.

Comment: I'll read the line a few times and see if I can make a clearer expression of the concept.

Comment: Isn't that more like the phrase "learning curve" (the rate of a person's progress in gaining experience or new skills.)?

Comment: I tested a different word.  But I thought it had to do with using what you already have for accelerating the rate of progress for a new experience.  (If you drive a volts wagon you may be able to drive a cadillac quicker than an overall new driver).

Comment: I felt there was a chance the question would be closed, but I never imagined the reason to be **not clear**, I thought it would be related to **opinions**.  But as I looked at it closer, it appeared there were some elements of specifics that could allow it to have a fairly specific answer.  His reference to **dash to panel** and **bottom** made it more specific where he was having issues.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do what you are looking for is to use Ubuntu in the form of Kubuntu or even better KDE Neon because of the KDE Plasma desktop.

Been already in a more familiar form for someone coming from Windows this can be a very important aspect. Also being so much customizable you can tweak a lot of option so to feel more comfortable as you try to get used to Ubuntu.

I personally believe that the most important aspect for people trying to get used to different operating systems is the desktop environment those operating systems are using. I think this is true especially for users that are not really serious about using programming or other specialized tools.

Generally speaking though, I don't think trying to get used to Ubuntu is going to be difficult especially if you really care to familiarize yourself with it and not simply to use it. Ubuntu is at its core easier than Windows in a lot of aspects. I personally find tweaking Windows and customize various settings is more difficult because their menus are a maze.

If you want to stick with Ubuntu though I believe that you don't really need to do much except for nostalgia reasons. As I said Ubuntu seems to me far simpler, especially for everyday usage. That is because:

1. You are not going to get stuck waiting for updates
2. You are not going to have to tweak antivirus software settings constantly
3. Installing programs in Ubuntu is a breeze
4. Navigating through settings is straightforward unlike Windows
5. You are not going to worry all the time for personal data notifications like in Windows.

The only thing that is going to help you immensely in the long run and is going to make the usage of Ubuntu far simpler is to just familiarize  yourself with the terminal a bit. Nothing difficult at first but you have to learn how to install software for it with the command

```
sudo apt install PACKAGE-NAME
```

and uninstall with

```
sudo apt remove PACKAGE-NAME
```

More commands are going to come as you go along, you really don't need to focus on that and get nervous or anything because you can work without even using the terminal. It is just really helpful

Another nice advice would be to stick with as many programs you had in Windows as you can because you are going to feel more comfortable that way.

Concluding, I believe people that come from Ubuntu and have to work in Windows have to make them more user friendly, not the other way around.